# Javascript Validate only .com websites how to validate?

Tags: javascript, regex, html, validation

**For Example:-**

google.com
msn.com

other than .com is not allowed how to wrote the regex?

Comment: `if ('google.com'.split('.').pop() === 'com') {...`?

Comment: I think similar question has already been answered here in Stackoverflow. Please check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/1403398

Comment: What about to write your solution of validation you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to ensure that the string ends with ".com" this regex should work :

`^.*\.com$`

Answer (score 0):

This is what foundation abide library states regex for validating a domain:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/
```

just modified it to only accept .com:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+com$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var site_path=window.location.origin;
var splitted_path=site_path.split(".");
if(splitted_path[splitted_path.length-1]=="com")
{
    // DO IF .COM.
}
else
{
    // DO IF ANOTHER.
}
```

Comment: you should give us more description ,it will be more easy to understand your method

Comment: Okay, First i get site url and split it by dot(.). Then check that spitted value's last element if .com or else other.

Answer (score 0):

Just split them when . comes and check if the current element is equals to .com for every element Your question answer is the below code:

```js
const validateCom = (str) =>{
    let total = ""
    let errorMessage = ""
    let error = false;
    if(str != null && str != ""){
        let array = str.split(".")
        array.forEach((element=>{
            if(element === "com"){
                total = "Yes, its .com"
                // Type your code if its .com here
            }else{
                total = "No, its not .com"
                // Type your code if its not .com here
            }
        }))
    }else{
        error = true;
        errorMessage = "Please fill the str perimeter"
        return errorMessage
    }
    return total;
}

// Calling Function
console.log(validateCom("demo.com"));
```